# How is memory managed while overwriting R objects?

Tags: r, performance, memory, bigdata

I'm handling some large datasets and am doing what I can to stay under R's memory limits.  One question came up regarding the overwriting of R objects.  I have a large `data.table` (or any R object), and it has to be copied to `tmp` multiple times.  The question is: does it make any difference if I delete `tmp` before overwriting it? In code:

```
for (1:lots_of_times) {
     v_l_d_t_tmp <- copy(very_large_data_table) # Necessary copy of 7GB data
                                                # table on 16GB machine. I can
                                                # afford 2 but not 3 copies.
     ### do stuff to v_l_d_t_tmp and output
     rm (v_l_d_t_tmp)  # The question is whether this rm keeps max memory
                        # usage lower, or if it is equivalent to what an 
                        # overwrite will automatically do on the next iteration.
}
```

Assume the copy is necessary (If I reach a point where I need to read `very_large_data_table` from disk at each loop, I'll do that, but the question stands: will it make any difference on max memory usage if I explicitly delete `v_l_d_t_tmp` before loading into it again?).

Or, to teach the man to fish, what could I have typed (within R, let's not get into `ps`) to answer this myself?

It's totally OK if the answer turns out to be: "Trust garbage collection."

Comment: Not an expert, but it shouldn't make a difference.  In either case, the original memory location is no longer pointed at by a symbol, so eligible for garbage collection (happy to be corrected by experts).  One thing to consider is whether your `data.table` really needs to be copied.  It is designed to be modified by reference so you don't have to do that.

Comment: As @BrodieG said using `rm` tells `R` that you no longer need to access `v_l_d_t_tmp` and the memory occupied by this table becomes eligible for garbage collection. However garbage collection does not take place when you call `rm`, but "automatically", when needed. This doesn't always work well,  so you can force garbage collection by calling `gc()` right after you call `rm(...)`. This may make your loop work. However in my experience you really need to restart R for the memory to be properly cleared (which would mean reading in your inputs for each iteration, probably quite slow).

Comment: From my own experience - trust garbage collector. We parsed genomic data and we have overwritten all data frames by the new ones, but I have no theoretical background supporting it...

Comment: @konvas I have had a similar experience... see my answer which re-casts the problem to avoid the memory allocation issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment more than an answer, but it is becoming too long.

I guess that in this case a call to `rm` might be proper. I think that starting from the second iteration, you may have 3 tables in memory if you don't call `rm`. While copying the large object, R cannot free the memory occupied by `v_l_d_t_tmp` before the end of the copy, since the function call may have an error and in this case the old object must be preserved. Consider this example:

```
 x<-1:10
 myfunc<-function(y) {Sys.sleep(3);30}
```

Here I defined an object and a function that takes some time to do something. If you try:

```
 x<-myfunc()
```

and break the execution before it ends "naturally", the object `x` still exists, with its `1:10` content. So, I guess that in your case, even if you use the same symbol, R cannot free its content before or during the copy. It can if you remove it before the following copy. Of course, the object will be removed after the copy, but you may run out of memory during it.

I'm not by any means an expert of the R internals, so don't take for granted what I just said.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another idea... it doesn't directly answer your question, instead tries to get around it by eliminating the memory problem in another way. Might get you thinking:

What if you instead cache the very_large_data_table, and then read it in just once, do what you need to do, and then exit R. Now, write a loop *outside of R*, and the memory problem vanishes. Granted, this costs you more CPU because you have to read in 7GB multiple times... but it might be worth saving the memory costs. In fact, this halves your memory use, since you don't have to ever copy the table.

In addition, like @konvas pointed out in the comments, I too found that `rm()` even with `gc()` never got me what I needed with a long loop, memory would just accumulate and eventually bog down. Exiting R is the easy way out.

I had to do this so often that I wrote a package to help me cache objects like this: [simpleCache](https://github.com/sheffien/simpleCache)

if you're interested in trying, it would look something like this:

do this outside of R:

```
for (1:lots_of_times) {
Rscript my_script.R
}
```

Then in R, do this... my_script.R:

```
library(simpleCache)
simpleCache("very_large_data_table", {r code for how 
you make this table }, assignTo="v_l_d_t_tmp") 

 ### do stuff to v_l_d_t_tmp and output
```

Comment: It's not great news for R if this is the right answer.  simpleCache looks great, thanks.